# Regex np++ Change different instances of "this" to different word

Tags: regex, notepad++, np

I have several of text files that contain the something like the following on many different lines:

```
this_is_THIS.doc
```

What I need to accomplish is to replace THIS with different objects for the first 5 occurrences and disregard the rest.

I would like for it to appear like the following:

```
this_is_TREE.doc
this_is_CAR.doc
this_is_CAT.doc
this_is_DONKEY.doc
this_is_ROCK.doc
```

I will have to do this many times in the future with the words changing so I feel a regex that I can alter in the future would help me a lot.  I have searched but found nothing useful.  Thanks for any help, you folks are great here.

Comment: For such a job especially if the number of `THIS`is large, you should write a script in favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you want to replace just 5 instances of `THIS`, I think the following solution is manageable. For this particular case, you can replace:

`^(.+?)THIS(.+?)THIS(.+?)THIS(.+?)THIS(.+?)THIS`

With

`$1TREE$2CAR$3CAT$4DONKEY$5ROCK`

Change the above texts like `CAT`, `CAR` as per your requirements.

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xI2DTe/1)

**Before Replacing:**

Don't forget to check `. matches newline` and `Match case` settings as shown below.
[image]

**After Replacing:**

[image]

*Note: Even I wouldn't recommend this method if you need to replace say 100 instances of `THIS`. The regex is going to be too long in that case.*

Comment: Excellent thank you.  I left home for a bit I will test shortly.  Appreciate it very much

Comment: No problem. Let me know, if it solves your issue or in case of any issues